# Demodulate qpsk with gnu radio

Tags: filters, filtering, demodulation, qpsk

I'm trying to demodulate a qpsk signal with gnu radio. The signal is from the meteor satellite on 137MHz https://www.sigidwiki.com/wiki/Low_Rate_Picture_Transmission_(LRPT).
I recorded the signal with gqrx without any special settings.

This is my flow graph:
[image]

After filtering the signal looks like this which doesn't look like a qpsk signal:
[image]

My input signal looks weird but the fft plot seems to be fine:
[image]
[image]

I already got pictures from it with other software (glrpt) so too much noise shouldn't be the problem.
Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: shouldn't the input signal have more, many more samples per cycle?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Sad, honest answer: no. This could be incorrect assumptions on symbol rate or frequency offset, an incorrect receive filter, a lack of equalization, too much noise, or the lack of timing recovery paired with bad luck. In any case, choosing a decimation where every symbol has 1.6 samples is ... not helping visualizing this, at all.

I honestly don't see anything that resembles the constant envelope that QPSK would have, though. So, if adjusting the decimation of your RRC such that there's an integer number of samples per symbol doesn't help, you should check your assumptions on your signal.

Comment: Already tried many things but nothing really changed anything. The recording is from the meteor satellite, from which i got pictures with other programs fine, so too much noise shouldn't be the problem. Could recording with a higher sample rate fix it?

Comment: I recommended somerthing specific. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes. Looks about the same

Comment: hm, then you'll have to simply check your assumptions, they are necessarily wrong.

Comment: Checked everything. I noticed my input signal looking weird (added picture in post) but the fft plot seems to display everything fine. Maybe there is some weird stuff going on with the recording?

Comment: that input signal looks like your assumption that you need an RRC is wrong, your assumption on symbol rate is wrong, and your assumption that it's QPSK is wrong! Other than that, it really looks very good. Try making a plot of all the complex values that occur in your input sample (i.e., mark all occuring values in the complex plane), and look whether your QPSK assumption holds.

Comment: The signal has to be qpsk (except if the sat was broken at the time of recording) and rrc filter is used in every demodulator i know. The symbol rate of the  signal is 72k https://www.sigidwiki.com/wiki/Low_Rate_Picture_Transmission_(LRPT). Mapping the input signal in a complex plane just gives me many points. Shouldn't the input signal be less choppy?

Comment: the picture you show as your input signal simply speaks a different language than your claim about it having to be QPSK, sorry. You inconveniently cut of the axes of your pictures, but the only other thing I could imagine is that your input signal is so weak that it only uses the 2 or 3 least significant bits and your actual signal hence could never be recovered, that would be the other explanation for the input signal taking only very few discrete values.

Comment: also, honestly, if you even have more info on what you think the signal should be **EDIT** your question to include all you know! Why leave us intentionally stumbling in the dark? At the very least the sigidwiki link, a description of the satellite and your carrier frequency would have been kind of necessary to include.

Comment: That could be the problem. I will try to record it again with different software/settings. Thanks for helping

Comment: **EDIT** your question. Until you at least include all information you've given in the comments here, people (including me) will vote to close it as unclear.

Comment: thank you very much!